# Way to send a s3 event notification to specific lambda alias or version

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

As the title of the question, Is there any way to send S3 event notification to specific alias or version of lambda function?

I tried to put lambda ARN with a version like `arn:aws:lambda:ap-northeast-1:xxxxx:function:xxxx:77` into `Lambda function ARN` but it doesn't work returning the below error.
(If I remove version info from the ARN, it works)

[image]

```
Unable to validate the following destination configurations. Not authorized to invoke function [arn:aws:lambda:ap-northeast-1:xxxxx:function:xxxx:77]. (arn:aws:lambda:ap-northeast-1:xxxxx:function:xxxx:77, null)
```

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on information from [Section 3.1.7 Connecting S3 to Lambda](https://forums.manning.com/posts/list/40256.page), you can add the event **from the AWS Lambda console** and it will work.

I tested it and it works... **the version number is correctly appended to the ARN**.